# Redshift to DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift

I have a Redshift table with a bunch of records in it (a few billion) which I want to put into DynamoDB and would like some help. Please see a simplified version of what I have:

```
CustomerID        Object        Color
0001              Cat           White
0001              Dog           Brown
0001              Lamp          White
0002              Car           Blue
0003              Fish          Blue
0003              House         Blue
```

Etc. A customer currently has as many records as they have objects. I want a Dynamo table which keeps the customer as the hash and stores all of the object-color pairs with the key.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a RedShift connector directly to DynamoDB, however, you can definitely [export from Redshift to S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Unloading_tables.html) and [import to DynamoDB from S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataPipelineExportImport.Importing.html).  In terms of DynamoDB, all you would need to do is setup a table with your desired schema (e.g. Hash - CustomerId - "String").

Comment: Thanks! I exported it from Redshift like this:

zip11{"n":"123456790"}mail1{"SS":["2015-06-15","2015-06-17","RevSpring-PA","FCM","Dummyvar"]}
zip11{"n":"123456789"}mail1{"SS":["2015-07-10","2015-07-12","Standard Register","FCM","Dummyvar"]}mail2{"SS":["2015-06-29","2015-07-01","Standard Register","FCM","Dummyvar"]}mail3{"SS":["2015-08-01","2015-08-03","helix EDUCATION","FCM","Dummyvar"]}mail4{"SS":["2015-07-24","2015-07-26","Standard Register","FCM","Dummyvar"]}

and so on but I get a "Supplied AttributeValue is empty" error. I checked and all {"SS": are followed by arrays